# how to return a data from custom command and to use it again in cypress

Tags: cypress

```
const { generateNum } = require("./generate_num")

Cypress.Commands.add('NewUserRegister', () => {
    const { userName, email, password} = generateNum();
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Sign up').click()
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(userName)
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(email)
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type(password)
        cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
});
```

I'm trying to create a custom command that will login to a user's page using this command's credentials.
I have no idea how to do it.
The data should be typed in this fields

```
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(?????????)
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(?????????)
```

So i did this

```
const { generateNum } = require("./generate_num")

Cypress.Commands.add('NewUserRegister', () => {
    const { userName, email, password} = generateNum();
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Sign up').click()
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(userName)
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(email)
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type(password)
        cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
    return cy.wrap(userName, email, password)
});
```

And this

```
it('log in register user', () => {
cy.then(data => {
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(data.email)
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(data.password)
cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
})
```

TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Comment: Whats the code of your `generateNum()` funciton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So idk what is. I just wrote everything that came into my head
so here is a custom command that create a new user and log after

its commands.js

```
const { generateNum } = require("./generate_num");

Cypress.Commands.add('NewUserRegister', () => {
const {userName, email, password} = generateNum() 
cy.visit('/')
const user = ({userName, email, password})
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Sign up').click();
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(userName);
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(email);
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .form-control').type(password);
cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click();
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Settings').click();
cy.get('.btn-outline-danger').should('contain.text', 'Or click here to logout').click()
.then(response => ({...user}))
```

});

So it's a .cy.js bc idk maybe custom command can't work inside other custom anyway

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const { generateNum } = require("../support/generate_num");

describe('', () => {
it('main_page', () => {
cy.NewUserRegister().then(user =>{
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .form-control').type(user.email)
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .form-control').type(user.password)
cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
})
});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing brackets on the return value.

```js
return cy.wrap({userName, email, password})
```

This gives you an object with properties that are not undefined.

Comment: its useful but i still have  TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Comment: `cy.then(data => ` isn't going to call the command, should be `cy.NewUserRegister().then(data => `